# MongoDb: how to combine result of say 5 match queries on a Collection and also sort result ordered by queries result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema something like this:

```
new Schema({
    first: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    last: { type: String, trim: true },
    third: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
    fourth: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
    fifth: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }
},options);

mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Say I have 1000 documents in this collection.

I want to sort these documents in such a way that:

first we have documents that match all the  field values of **the particular User**(i.e a match with all five field value of a particular document)

then a match with next four fields of that user, after that a match with  next three 
fields and so on.

Say first match found 100 documents,

then second will find previous 100 + 200(i.e new 200 docs which match with the next three fields of that User) and so on.

**After this calculation I want to show first match sorted result first and then second match sorted result and so on.**

How can I do this using mongoose?

Comment: Sorted by what field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use an aggregate.

```
[{ 
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        matchCount: {
            $sum: {
                { $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$first', first] } }, then: 1, else: 0 },
                { $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$last', last] } }, then: 1, else: 0 },
                { $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$third', third] } }, then: 1, else: 0 },
                { $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$fourth', fourth] } }, then: 1, else: 0 },
                { $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$fifth', fifth] } }, then: 1, else: 0 },
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        matchCount: -1
    }
},
{
    $limit: 200
}]
```